# Limit to size of dropdown in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

is there a limit to the number of items which can be built into a dropdown in Excel via VBA?

I am getting an "application-defined or object-defined" error and I believe the characters in my list are perfectly fine- except I have ~530 values in my dropdown?

EDIT: I have found out through trial and error there is a character limit of 1861 characters. Is there any work around?

Comment: Hi Porcupine, This is _absolutely not_ a solution to your problem but I'm just curious on one thing: What happens if you populate a random dropdown in Excel with > 530 100% error free strings?

Comment: @Hauns, will try! Could be a total characters limit.....

Comment: Just did a for loop creating 1000 numbers, 1 to 1000 and this worked. Changed it to 100000 and i got the same error....

Comment: Well @Porcupine, I think the solution is in the data which you have used to populate your origin dropdown.

Comment: @Hauns, its a character limit. 1861 characters is the maximum

Comment: Do you have to display 1861 characters/item in your dropdownlist?

Comment: @Hauns, pretty much- Ive got names of ~530 "books" (not the type you read) and the user can filter data based upon the book name. It'd be hard to expect them to know the book ID numbers....

Comment: @Its to do with the maximum length of a formula because I use .AddType:=Formula1:DropDownList

Comment: A dropdown with 530 options is a pretty mean thing to inflict on a user... Have you considered a ListBox or some other solution instead?

Comment: If you're using the Data Validation feature to create the dropdown (as opposed to some kind of control), you can set up the list of allowed values in a range of cells on a worksheet, and then specify this range (as opposed to a list of literal values) as the source of the dropdown list.  This doesn't appear to have the same character limit.

Answer (score 0):

MS says: 
*The maximum number of entries that you can have in a drop-down list is 32,767*

What I'm finding out is the limit (in a VSTO C# Excel ribbon drop down) is 1,000 items. These items are strings of various size ranging from a few characters to maybe 50 chars.